# Assets and Member Group Permissions

Tags: assets, permissions

I recently installed '[Assets](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets)' by Pixel & Tonic for a client that has multiple member groups with access to the control panel. Each member group has varying permissions level. The install went fine, but as I was writing up the instructions for one of the members group, I switch my control panel access to a user within that group, 'writers' and notice that none of the images display in the Assets field.

Here is the field, a mini-photo-gallery, viewed as a super-admin

[image: Assets SuperAdmin View]

This is the same field, same record, viewed as a writer

[image: Assets Writer's View]

I've adjusted the setting under the 'Writers' group, so that they now have access to the Assets Module (which I'm not certain is required), but they still can't view the added images, except on the front-end.

This seems to be directly related to permissions, but I can't seem to find what permissions are stopping a writer from viewing content that's obviously in the record. Especially, when they can add new items to the record.

So my question is, where should I go to look for other permissions that maybe interfering with the display of the images? We need all the groups that have access to the field_type, to be able to see what data has already been added to it, so that they don't re-add or can just verify that the correct photos have been added.

I've not had to deal with this in other installs of Assets, because generally there is just SuperAdmins and one member group level, like 'staff' who have access to the control panel.

**Updated:** The site is running ExpressionEngine 2.5.3, Build Date: 20120911 and Assets 1.2.2.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  My first thought was to check the member group preferences for each file upload preference.  Are you running any other add-ons that work with members, such as Zoo Visitor or similar?

Comment: Nope. The site just uses the built-in EE functionality, because we don't allow members to really do anything of interest. It's just the staff that have control panel privileges, but staff is divided into various work groups, like training, advocacy, outreach, editors, publishers, etc. I'm going to check on another computer, to see if maybe its a browser issue. It's never happen before, but the only other set-ups we've used it on were: superadmin, staff, members (with members having no control panel access at all).

Comment: Okay more testing… I've checked on second machine, same issue. Both tests were in Safari. This time, I did verify, which was a concern, if the user adds a new image, will the former images disappear? Seems like the answer is yes. I've checked permission everywhere I can think of, but my brains fried, had to deal with a massive data spike for a client who was featured in the news.

Comment: nonprofit_tech, can you email your Superadmin and FTP details to support@pixelandtonic.com - and mention this thread - and I'll have a look?  Thank you!

Comment: I sent access details, with two sample records, so you can see the behavior. You should be good to go.

Comment: Responded with my primary recommendation to upgrade to Assets 2 - which is where I can't reproduce this. :)

Comment: The site can't be upgraded without a plan. I tested and 2.0.3 caused a number of issues on our test server. They maybe easy to deal with, we just don't have the time right now to deal with them, when 1.x has been fine, except for this recent discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad ended up figuring this one out:

> "The images that were selected by the Super Admin are all coming from
>   the "Event Images" upload folder (specifically the
>   2008_Madison_Symposium subfolder) and the "outreach" member group does
>   not have permissions to upload to that folder."

Assets should still have let them view those images - and that will be fixed in a future release.  The workaround for now is to give that member group permission to that event images file upload preference.

Comment: Thank you! I'm good with this work-around, until we can upgrade them.